# ¿Como poder guardar y enviar valores con la letra Ñ usando postgres y Express?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, express

Cuando hago una petición a la base de datos usando Express y PG pidiendo que me devuelva toda la información donde la profesión es igual a albañil el JSON que recibo es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En vez de recibir albañil, obtengo alba¤il. Entonces que tengo que hacer?

Comment: especifica la codificación, esta debe estar en `UTF-8` tanto en la BD como al interpretar la respuesta

Comment: @Christian justamente la base de datos ya esta en UTF-8

Comment: y te lo sigue mostrando asi?

Comment: @Christian si es por eso que ya no ser que hacer

Comment: decodifica los datos en utf8

Comment: @Christian a si tengo mi base de datos configurada

Comment: decodifica el texto en la respuesta, creo que existia un modulo de node o se tenia que hacer una configuración para especificar el formato

Comment: Raro que tengas la base de datos en utf8 y que no los devuelva en ese formato lol, trata de pasar lo que recibes de postgres por un `StringDecoder` del modulo `string_decoder`, pero vuelvo y repito, es raro, deberías confirmar cuidadosamente la config de tu db

Comment: como dice @AnkiJedi si es muy raro, además como consejo pon tu imagen del JSON como texto, tu pregunta me apareció como *"reportada como baja calidad"*